# Android background doesnt show correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, background

Ok I have created a background image in Inkscape. Exported that image and it looks correct, when I open it from Eclipse. However, when I build the project and apply that background to the Layout, it shows the complete opposite in the designer and on the device.

Here is what the image is supposed to look like. [Correct background](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-UuW54W9-2WA/TzgV5ZkpS7I/AAAAAAAAAZ0/9AwVG35Z2oo/w250/list_view_bg.png)

Here is what the image looks like in the Eclipse Designer.[Incorrect background.](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-DIisxjkB-hc/TzgV0SGpN0I/AAAAAAAAAZU/NjpeuWPHSwU/h301/list_view_error.PNG)

Here is my Xml on a brand new Xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/list_view_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I am utterly confused on this one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely using a theme where the background in dark. As your background gradient is transparent the black background is showing through.

Switch to a light theme.

Comment: Glad it worked! To accept an answer press the tick to the left of it :) Good luck with your app!